# Vertical line spacing in html rendered text

Tags: java, swing

Java supports only an old html standard, but is there a more elegant way to increase the line spacing in a JComponent than my somewhat clumsy looking workaround?

I first used `<span style="line-height:...">` to no avail and ended up in adding a second break in each line after changing the font size.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class HtmlLineSpacing extends JFrame {

  public HtmlLineSpacing() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setTitle("JLabels with HTML text");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    JLabel lb= new JLabel("""
    <html><u>Regular</u><br>
    Line 1<br>
    Line 2<br>
    Line 3<br>
    Line 4</html>""");
    add(lb);
    add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(30));

//  Other attempts
//  <html><span style="line-height:150%">Line 1<br>
//  <html><span style="line-height:20pt">Line 1<br>
//  <html><span style="line-height:20px">Line 1<br>
//  <html><span style="line-height:5mm">Line 1<br>
    lb= new JLabel("""
    <html><u>Failure</u><br>
    <span style="line-height:1.7">
    Line 1<br>
    Line 2<br>
    Line 3<br>
    Line 4<br></span></html>""");
    add(lb);
    add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(30));

    lb= new JLabel("""
    <html><u>Workaround</u><br>
    Line 1<br>
    <span style="font-size:3pt"><br></span>
    Line 2<br>
    <span style="font-size:3pt"><br></span>
    Line 3<br>
    <span style="font-size:3pt"><br></span>
    Line 4<br></span></html>""");
    add(lb);
    add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(30));

    lb= new JLabel("""
    <html><u>Two full line breaks</u><br>
    Line 1<br><br>
    Line 2<br><br>
    Line 3<br><br>
    Line 4</html>""");
    add(lb);
    pack();
    setVisible(true);
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(HtmlLineSpacing::new);
  }

}
```

Comment: The more elegant way is to use [JTextAreas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html).

Comment: You can also use a one-column table without borders in HTML.

Comment: @Gilbert Since JTextAreas cannot handle html, I suppose you mean JEditor- or JTextPanes. To my knowledge the "html driver", if I may say so, is one and the same for all JComponents. Hence JEditor- and JTextPanes, too, ignore <span style="line-height:...">

Comment: The OP's HMTL contains <br>.  A `JTextArea` can handle line breaks just fine.

Comment: @Gilbert Do `JTextAreas` handle line spacing as well - beyond multiple \n? If so, please give me a hint, for I missed this.

Comment: You need to define exactly what you want.  If you want to control the individual row heights, then you need a `JEditorPane` or `JTextPane`.  If you want all the rows the same height, the default being the font height, then a `JTextArea` works well enough.

Comment: Okay, I want to increase the line spacing only (the same spacing for all lines) and not increase the font size.

Answer (score 0):

Sergiy Medvynskyy's suggestion works. Thank you.

```
    lb= new JLabel("""
    <html><table cellspacing=4 cellpadding=0>
    <tr><u>Table</u></tr>
    <tr>Line 1</tr>
    <tr>Line 2</tr>
    <tr>Line 3</tr>
    <tr>Line 4</tr>
    </html>""");
```

Adjust line spacing in modifying the *cellspacing* parameter.